# Adding linked list to constructor

Tags: c++, header

I;m not really sure what to call the issue I'm having but it's been bugging me for a half hour now trying to solve it. I'm trying to pass an Item class to a linked list in the player class as an inventory, but I'm having trouble doing so. The player.cpp doesn;t recognize the Item class and calls it "class DLinkedList<>". I am also not sure on adding the linkedlist to the constructor itself.

```
#include "player.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "DLinkedList.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Constructor
//  Description:    Constructor
//  Arguments:      
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------

player::player(){
    this ->name = "default";
    this ->lvl = 99;
    this ->exp = 99;
    this ->maxweight = 99;
    this ->currentweight = 99;
    this ->health = 99;
    this ->strenght = 99;
    this ->defence = 99;
    this -> //trying to add linked list here
}

player::player( string name, int level, int experience, double maxweight, double   currentweight, int health, int strenght, int defence, DLinkedList<Item> inventory){
    this ->name = name;
    this ->lvl = lvl;
    this ->exp = exp;
    this ->maxweight = maxweight;
    this ->currentweight = currentweight;
    this ->health = health;
    this ->strenght = strenght;
    this ->defence = defence;       
}
```

Here is the player header also

```
class player{
public:

//Data members
string name;
int lvl;
int exp;    
double maxweight;
double currentweight;
int health;
int strenght;
int defence;
DLinkedList<Item> inventory;

//Constructor
player();
player(string name, int level, int experience, double maxweight, double currentweight, int health, int strenght, int defence, DLinkedList<Item> inventory);
~player();
```

Comment: Can you describe what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit ahead of myself. I've edited it above to try and explain what the issue it is but I'm not entirely sure of it myself to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

```
this -> //trying to add linked list here
```

should be:

```
this ->inventory(); //trying to add linked list here
```

A few things of note:

- you don't need `this->` in front of members.
- your code will be better (smaller and more efficient) if you use initializer lists

Example:

```
player::player():
     name("default"),
     lvl(99),
     // and so on
     inventory()
{
}
```

- The members of your player class should (probably) be private

Comment: Thanks, I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to Linked Lists, and that this->inventory() seemed to work, and I'll try and optimize the constructors once I'm sure I've got it working, unfortunately I'm still getting the error in the overloaded constructor about the DLinkedList<error type> and saying that Item is not a type name. Also; I've heard people mention that before. What exactly would change if I made the class private?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that DLinkedList has a constructor with no arguments that constructs an empty linked list, you shouldn't need to do anything. The compiler will add a call to the default constructor for the object.

You will need a copy or assignment constructor in the `player::player( string name, int level, int experience, double maxweight, double   currentweight, int health, int strenght, int defence, DLinkedList<Item> inventory)` constructor tho'.